# Adding HTML after each IMG tag on the page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add additional html after each image on the page. But, for some reason, it doesn't accept the 'img' tag. If I put 'p' tag, it works, but not for images.

`$("img").append("Some text");`

Any idea why this is or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `after('Some text')` instead of `append('Some text')`.

`append()` method puts the content inside the specified element whereas `after()` puts the content after the specified element.

Answer (score 5):

Use `.after()` instead

`$("img").after("Some text");`

`.append()` puts your string within the `img` tag but `.after()` puts it after the `img` tag